# get node from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config>   
   <MetadataFormConfig FieldInternalName="Test">
      <Tabs>
         <Tab Title="A to C" Order="1">
            <ShowParentTerm>A</ShowParentTerm>
            <ShowParentTerm>B</ShowParentTerm>
            <ShowParentTerm>C</ShowParentTerm>
         </Tab>
         <Tab Title="D to E" Order="2">
            <ShowParentTerm>D</ShowParentTerm>
            <ShowParentTerm>E</ShowParentTerm>
         </Tab>
      </Tabs>   
   </MetadataFormConfig>  
</Config>
```

I want to get all the nodes by FieldInternalName.

Can please give a way how I can do this?

Comment: What do you expect as output?? A list of `XmlNode` objects? A list of strings?? What??

Comment: i want whole Tabs attribute. and then i need to get the value A,B,C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq version for getting all the nodes by FieldInternalName.

```
 // Loading from a file, you can also load from a stream
        XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"d:\test.xml");
        // Query the data 
        var query = from c in loaded.Descendants("MetadataFormConfig")
                where (string)c.Attribute("FieldInternalName") == "Test"
                select c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectNodes("/Config/MetadataFormConfig[@FieldInternalName='Test']")`

Check the details on [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx)

Comment: thanks. i got it. but can you please tell me how to get Tab Title attribute. for Ex: A to C

Comment: @Suresh - Well, this is a perfect candidate for Linq to be used. You need to research a bit on Linq.xml in c# (hope you are using v3.5 or above). using Linq, getting this info is a piece of cake, unfortunately I am not clear on syntax there.

Comment: @Suresh - You can still continue to use the selectnodes to get the values as desired by you, but that will be lot of code required. Using Linq its just one line of code for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can test your own xpath expression and refine it until you get your desired result, there are plenty of XPATH testers online, for example here is one: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

just go there, paste your xml fragment from above and work with XPATH untill you get what you need.